# HashMap of HashMaps Not Populating as Expected

Tags: java, hash

I am attempting to download data from a database and populate a hash map of a hash map of a hash map of a hash map of string values. I would expect each key would be unique (which it is) and to be assigned only to the key it is associated with when using the put method. This is the part that is breaking down. It assigns multiple duplicate keys and the final values always end up overwriting the previous values even though not associated with that particular key.

```
<pre><code>
    Map<String, String> attribs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> altKey = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> posKey = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String,  Map<String, String>>>();
    Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> variantData = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>();

    //skipping the database code here...

    while (rs.next()) {

                    attribs.put("ref", rs.getString(3));
                    attribs.put("genotype", rs.getString(5));
                    altKey.put(rs.getString(4), attribs);
                    posKey.put(rs.getInt(2), altKey);
                    variantData.put(rs.getString(1), posKey);
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getString(1)
                            + "\t" + rs.getInt(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(4) + "\t"
                            + rs.getString(3) + "\t" + rs.getString(5));

                }
                System.out.println("\n" + "------------------------" + "\n");

                Iterator<String> keySetIterator = variantData.keySet().iterator();

                while (keySetIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keySetIterator.next();
                    Iterator<Integer> posSetIterator = variantData.get(key)
                            .keySet().iterator();
                    while (posSetIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Integer pos = posSetIterator.next();
                        Iterator<String> altSetIterator = variantData.get(key)
                                .get(pos).keySet().iterator();
                        while (altSetIterator.hasNext()) {
                            String alt = altSetIterator.next();
                            System.out.println("key 1: "
                                    + key
                                    + " key 2: "
                                    + pos
                                    + " key 3: "
                                    + alt
                                    + " values: "
                                    + variantData.get(key).get(pos).get(alt)
                                            .values());

                        }

                    }

                }
</code></pre>

<pre>

This produces the following output:

The raw output from the database:

<pre>
chr4    78962253    C   CT                      1|0
chr4    38391318    G   GAAGGGACCAGTCAAAGGGT    1|0
chr4    169518074   A   ATAGCACTTTTACCCT        1|0
chr4    3756414     A   AC                      1|0
chr4    130827032   T   TA                      0|1</pre>

------------------------

And the results of iterating over the structure:


key 1: chr4 key 2: 38391318 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 38391318 key 3: G values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 38391318 key 3: A values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 38391318 key 3: C values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 3756414 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 3756414 key 3: G values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 3756414 key 3: A values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 3756414 key 3: C values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 130827032 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 130827032 key 3: G values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 130827032 key 3: A values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 130827032 key 3: C values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 78962253 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 78962253 key 3: G values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 78962253 key 3: A values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 78962253 key 3: C values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 169518074 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 169518074 key 3: G values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 169518074 key 3: A values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 169518074 key 3: C values: [TA, 0|1]


My expected output would be something like this:


key 1: chr4 key 2: 38391318 key 3: G values: [GAAGGGACCAGTCAAAGGGT, 1|0]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 3756414 key 3: A values: [AC, 1|0]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 130827032 key 3: T values: [TA, 0|1]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 78962253 key 3: C values: [CT, 1|0]
key 1: chr4 key 2: 169518074 key 3: A values: [ATAGCACTTTTACCCT, 1|0]

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or am I simply using the wrong collection type for this problem.

Thanks,
</pre>
```

Comment: Please just use an `Object`! `Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>`?? Come on...

Comment: Or use a JPA framework with appropriate model classes.

Comment: OK. So I am going to interpret this to mean that nested hashmaps are inadequate for this type of task. When you say use an object, I don't any to even guess how that might happen with all of the data I have to evaluate (billions of records). Can you point me towards some documentation on how to use an Object that emulates a data structure. What impact will instantiating billions of objects have on a system?

Comment: Billions of records? And you want to download and store them all at once? This doesn't sound like a good idea. Try to slice this data into appropriate pieces and evaluate them separately.

Comment: Yeah Tom I definitely will do that. Getting back to my original issue though, is there any documentation you can point me to to use Objects in lieu of HashMaps to pull this all together. Normally I would just build a data structure this way in Python for this but the job is too big for that language. I need something in Java that will translate from Hash Tables to Objects (or the JPA as you mentioned).

Comment: If I understand @BoristheSpider correctly, he meant to declare these variables as `Object`, but you still initialize them with your Map structure. So there wouldn't be any differences except some type casts.